# Getting strings from list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

Hi I am new to python I am trying to delete some unwanted characters and bring format

My lists are

```
List=
['2', '4a.', 'D', '__|5.', 'E|6.', 'F', '|7.', 'G', '—|8.'']
['9', '10.', "QRS(q,r", 's)', '11.', 'TUV/', '12.', "XYZ:"]
```

I want to get the list as follows

```
['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
["QRS(q,r,s)", 'TUV/', "XYZ:"]
```

Here I want to delete numbers and alphanumeric ones
There are two challenges here

```
in the first list I had 'E|6.' I want to get E only string

in the second list I had "QRS(q,r", 's)' I want it as "QRS(q,r,s)" as only one string
```

Can anyone plz help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what you have done already?

Comment: Is there a whitelist or blacklist of characters you want to keep?

Comment: @TomS yes 1.(all numbers like this) , 1a.(numbers with char), __|3.(two underscores with num), |4.(pipe with numbers)

Comment: [1.,1a.,__|3.,|4.,] like this all possible ones need to be deleted @TomS

Comment: @AmitNanaware tried splitting everything but not worked

Comment: your first problem is just [`.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

Comment: what's the logic on the second list, just group together strings that have a `(` in them but not `)` and vice versa?

Comment: I want the two problems need to be filtered once and print the two Lists could you plz me @Chase

Comment: @anand Please explain the logic behind your second list - read my previous comment.

Comment: @Chase make these two strings "QRS(q,r", 's)' into "QRS(q,r,s)" into one like this

Comment: @anand and what is the logic there? group together strings that have a ( in them but not ) and vice versa?

Comment: @Chase group the strings in bracket with qrs

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to differentiate between an special character and a alphabet character. For this you must have a list of limited alphabet characters -

```
import string
string.ascii_lowercase # returns all alphabets in lowercase.
```

Then you will need to iterate through the string in the list as to find possible alphabets in uppercase.

```
import string
List = ['2', '4a.', 'D', '__|5.', 'E|6.', 'F', '|7.', 'G', '—|8.'],['9', '10.', "QRS(q,r", 's)', '11.', 'TUV/', '12.', "XYZ:"]
what_you_need = []
for h in List:
  for i in h:
    for j in i:
      if j.upper() in string.ascii_lowercase.upper():
          what_you_need.append(j)
print(what_you_need)
```

Comment: I want the two lists need to be filtered once

Comment: like at the same time?

Comment: @anand do you want them to be filtered one at a time or through multhreading, do both preferrably one after one

Comment: I want them to be filtered once and print the two lists

Comment: Okay, i have edited my code in the answer. should help :)

Comment: I want to get the output two different lists but filtered ones thats the challenge

like this ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
             ["QRS(q,r,s)", 'TUV/', "XYZ:"]

Comment: oh okay now i understand. so the double quoted item should be joined to whatever item is in front of it?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find a way to get if whether the string is double quoted or single quoted. You should try and make another way to signify that the item is to be joined to the item ahead of it (like putting double quotes inside single quotes in which the string can go so it knows.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try regular expression.

check below example:

```
import re
l1 = []
a = ['2', '4a.', 'D', '__|5.', 'E|16.', 'F', '|7.', 'G', '—|8.']
for idx, ele in enumerate(a):
    if '(' in ele:
        l1.append(ele + ',' + b[idx+1])
        continue
    elif ')' in ele:
        pass
    elif any([i.isdigit() for i in ele]):
        g = re.findall(r"([A-Z])",ele)
        if g:
            l1.append(g[0])
    else:
        l1.append(ele)
```

In same way you can prepare regular expression for another list

Comment: I want the two regular expressions need to work once and when I print(List) I want the filtered two lists could you please help me how can I do it

Comment: @ Amit Nanaware

Comment: @anand updated the answer. Please check it. you can pass any list to this code